# How to ping an IP address in Delphi 10.1 without using Indy components?

Tags: delphi, ping, icmp

How to ping an IP address (or by server name) in Delphi 10.1 without using Indy components? TIdICMPClient works with elevated privileges but I want to do it as a normal user.

Comment: You can only ping an IP address, so you would have to resolve the IP via DNS if you have a hostname instead. Once you have an IP, you can use `IcmpSendEcho()` on Windows. On OSX, and maybe also Linux, you can use a UDP socket to send/receive ICMP echo packets without needing admin rights

Comment: @Remy It must take a lot of guts to respond calmly to someone who doesn't want to use your pride and joy :-/

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm well aware that `TIdIcmpClient` only works with admin rights, and it is not uncommon to want to ping without them.

Comment: @Remy, why does Indy require elevated privileges for pinging?

Comment: @Johan because Indy implements ICMP manually using a RAW socket, and RAW sockets require admin rights on modern OSes. When `TIdIcmpClient` was first written, Windows was the only OS supported, and Microsoft hadn't locked down the use of RAW sockets yet.

Comment: A few years ago I wrote a ping method using WMI And Delphi. Try this  https ://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/02/02/making-a-ping-with-delphi-and-the-wmi/

Answer (score 7):

The other answers had some things missing from them.

Here is a complete unit that does the trick:

```
unit Ping2;

interface

function PingHost(const HostName: AnsiString; TimeoutMS: cardinal = 500): boolean;

implementation

uses Windows, SysUtils, WinSock;

function IcmpCreateFile: THandle; stdcall; external 'iphlpapi.dll';
function IcmpCloseHandle(icmpHandle: THandle): boolean; stdcall;
  external 'iphlpapi.dll';
function IcmpSendEcho(icmpHandle: THandle; DestinationAddress: In_Addr;
  RequestData: Pointer; RequestSize: Smallint; RequestOptions: Pointer;
  ReplyBuffer: Pointer; ReplySize: DWORD; Timeout: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall;
  external 'iphlpapi.dll';

type
  TEchoReply = packed record
    Addr: In_Addr;
    Status: DWORD;
    RoundTripTime: DWORD;
  end;

  PEchoReply = ^TEchoReply;

var
  WSAData: TWSAData;

procedure Startup;
begin
  if WSAStartup($0101, WSAData) <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('WSAStartup');
end;

procedure Cleanup;
begin
  if WSACleanup <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('WSACleanup');
end;

function PingHost(const HostName: AnsiString;
  TimeoutMS: cardinal = 500): boolean;
const
  rSize = $400;
var
  e: PHostEnt;
  a: PInAddr;
  h: THandle;
  d: string;
  r: array [0 .. rSize - 1] of byte;
  i: cardinal;
begin
  Startup;
  e := gethostbyname(PAnsiChar(HostName));
  if e = nil then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if e.h_addrtype = AF_INET then
    Pointer(a) := e.h_addr^
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Name doesn''t resolve to an IPv4 address');

  d := FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnsszzz', Now);

  h := IcmpCreateFile;
  if h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    i := IcmpSendEcho(h, a^, PChar(d), Length(d), nil, @r[0], rSize, TimeoutMS);
    Result := (i <> 0) and (PEchoReply(@r[0]).Status = 0);
  finally
    IcmpCloseHandle(h);
  end;
  Cleanup;
end;

end.
```

You can call it with a click event like this:

```
procedure TForm1.button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PingHost('172.16.24.2') then
    ShowMessage('WORKED')
  else
    ShowMessage('FAILED');
end;
```

Remember to add the "Ping2" unit in your `uses` list.

Comment: I tried your unit, it was a fine version of `IcmpSendEcho` usage, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Windows API.

Something like this crude translation from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx
Should do the trick.

```
var
  ICMPFile: THandle;
  IpAddress: ULONG;
  SendData: array[0..31] of AnsiChar;
  ReplyBuffer: PICMP_ECHO_REPLY;
  ReplySize: DWORD;
  NumResponses: DWORD;
begin
  IpAddress:= inet_addr('127.0.0.1');
  SendData := 'Data Buffer';

  IcmpFile := IcmpCreateFile;
  if IcmpFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    try
      ReplySize:= SizeOf(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + SizeOf(SendData);
      GetMem(ReplyBuffer, ReplySize);
      try
        NumResponses := IcmpSendEcho(IcmpFile, IPAddress, @SendData, SizeOf(SendData),
                      nil, ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 1000);
        if (NumResponses <> 0) then begin
          Writeln(Format('Received %d icmp message responses', [NumResponses]));
          Writeln('Information from the first response:');
          Writeln(Format('Received from %s', [inet_ntoa(in_addr(ReplyBuffer.Address))]));
          Writeln(Format('Data: %s', [PAnsiChar(ReplyBuffer.Data)]));
          Writeln(Format('Status = %d', [ReplyBuffer.Status]));
          WriteLn(Format('Roundtrip time = %d milliseconds',[ReplyBuffer.RoundTripTime]));
        end else begin
          WriteLn('Call to IcmpSendEcho failed');
          WriteLn(Format('IcmpSendEcho returned error: %d', [GetLastError]));
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(ReplyBuffer);
      end;
    finally
      IcmpCloseHandle(IcmpFile);
    end
  else begin
    Writeln('Unable to open handle');
    Writeln(Format('IcmpCreateFile returned error: %d', [GetLastError]));
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Delphi unit which does the ping with a timeout:

```
unit Ping2;

interface

function PingHost(const HostName:string;TimeoutMS:cardinal=500):boolean;

implementation

uses Windows, SysUtils, WinSock, Sockets;

function IcmpCreateFile:THandle; stdcall; external 'iphlpapi.dll';
function IcmpCloseHandle(icmpHandle:THandle):boolean; stdcall; external 'iphlpapi.dll'
function IcmpSendEcho(IcmpHandle:THandle;DestinationAddress:In_Addr;RequestData:Pointer;
  RequestSize:Smallint;RequestOptions:pointer;ReplyBuffer:Pointer;ReplySize:DWORD;
  Timeout:DWORD):DWORD; stdcall; external 'iphlpapi.dll';

type
  TEchoReply=packed record
    Addr:in_addr;
    Status:DWORD;
    RoundTripTime:DWORD;
    //DataSize:
    //Reserved:
    //Data:pointer;
    //Options:
  end;
  PEchoReply=^TEchoReply;

function PingHost(const HostName:string;TimeoutMS:cardinal=500):boolean;
const
  rSize=$400;
var
  e:PHostEnt;
  a:PInAddr;
  h:THandle;
  d:string;
  r:array[0..rSize-1] of byte;
  i:cardinal;
begin
  //assert WSAStartup called
  e:=gethostbyname(PChar(HostName));
  if e=nil then RaiseLastOSError;
  if e.h_addrtype=AF_INET then pointer(a):=e.h_addr^ else raise Exception.Create('Name doesn''t resolve to an IPv4 address');

  d:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnsszzz',Now);

  h:=IcmpCreateFile;
  if h=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    i:=IcmpSendEcho(h,a^,PChar(d),Length(d),nil,@r[0],rSize,TimeoutMS);
    Result:=(i<>0) and (PEchoReply(@r[0]).Status=0);
  finally
    IcmpCloseHandle(h);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: How can I solve this error: F2613 Unit 'Sockets' not found.

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408939/delphi-cant-find-units-in-the-library-path